# Spark AQE coalesce not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote a small PySpark code to test the working of spark AQE, and doesn't seem to coalesce the partitions as per the parameters passed to it.

Following is my code :

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(<path to my csv file>)

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled","true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","50")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum", "60")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes","200000")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.parallelismFirst","false")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.minPartitionSize", "200000")

df3 = df.groupby("Loan title").agg({"*":"count"}).withColumnRenamed('count(1)','cnt')
df3.show()
```

The file is ~ 1.8 Gb and gets read into 14 partitions and its shuffle write is ~ 1.8MB and I have set the advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes and minPartitionSize as 200 kb, so I expected the number of coalesce partitions to be around 9 (1M/200kb).

But eventhough we see 8 coalesced partitions in AQEshuffle reader in the final plan, the number of tasks in the final stage is still 1 which is confusing.

Please find the spark ui images below :

[physical plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QMCv.png)

[stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8jsg.png)

Could anyone help me in figuring out this behavior ? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trials I figured out the issue. The shuffle write for the final stage was not equal to the shuffle read because of the `df3.show()` command. This was only reading some of the input to take to the driver as all the answers are not shown.

Once I changed this to `.write` or `df3.rdd.getNumPartitions()`. I can see the expected number of tasks/partitions getting created because now all the partitions are being read.

Please find the screenshots below:

[Stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baiIY.png)

Stages 18 - 20 : `df3.show()`

Stages 21 - 23 : `df3.write.format("csv").save(..)`